# Wolfram Tech Conference 2015

Tags: discussion

[image: banner]

About that time of the year. I'm going for the first time this year.

Anybody else going, and would there be any interest in an SE-meetup?

Comment: I'm going, arriving late Sunday, and will be happy to meet up. It will be my first time, too.

Comment: I arrive late Monday- I think a SE meetup would be a great idea

Comment: Okay. I arrive Monday 5-ish. Let me look around and find something close. Try to shoot for Monday evening, maybe? @Verbeia

Comment: See above @PeterRoberge. iPhone app won't let me put more than one (at) reply in a comment.

Comment: @kale - sounds great. Maybe set up an event in the pathable site?

Comment: I've set up a meeting. It's at http://wtc15.pathable.com/meetings/331655.

Comment: @kale got the meeting- but I arrive at 9PM on Monday, so i would vote later in the week!

Comment: @Verbeia http://i.stack.imgur.com/QN7SE.png

Comment: @kale That link doesn't work for me -- it claims I don't have permission to view it. :-P

Comment: @BrettChampion I'm a pathable noob. I'll add you, but I don't see a way to make it public. Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot attend this year, but wish you a great conference! To go with AC/DC: have a drink on me !  With all the SE folks around this is bound to be fun  event.

Comment: Not this year. New kid and my back-up is having carpal tunnel surgery. Hopefully next year.

Comment: @kale, need permission to view pathable link.

Comment: Looking forward to meet you all @ WTC15

Comment: Would any of you conference attendees be willing to write about your experience(s) for the site blog?

Comment: @J.M. I can scratch down some thoughts. Email me what you're thinking and I'll see if I can get a post together.

Comment: @kale, I think Verbeia's in charge with the blog; write something up, and you can ask her how to publish it there. For an example, look for Yves's blog entry about a previous conference.

Answer (score 11):

After a few venue changes, we made it! Thanks Kale for arranging the event and Brett for organising the table.

Front row: Kale, user21, Stan Silver

Back row: Peter Roberge, Chip Hurst, Zviovich, Anton Antonov (obscured), me, P Fonseca, Edmund and Daniel Lichtblau

[image]

Comment: Pleasure meeting u @verbeia

Comment: Haha! That's the elusive @user21 in the middle front row. Great meeting everyone.

Comment: I think image processing using mathematica should allow us to guess user21's name from his name tag ;-)

Comment: So, why isn't @Brett in the picture? :)

Comment: Sorry I missed this!

Comment: "Brett's gone -- take the photo now!"

Comment: It was great to put faces to user names!

Comment: What happened to me on this photo is similar to what happened to [Mike Wazowski in the Monsters Inc. commercial](http://www.cornel1801.com/disney/Monsters-Inc-2001/pictures/15.jpg).

Comment: @Anton, you should've asked for a retake! :)

Comment: @J.M. I became aware of my obscured presence in the *chosen* photo ten days after the conference.

Comment: @Anton, hopefully you can ensure that you're not eclipsed in the pictures this year. :)

Comment: @J.M. I will definitely try!

Answer (score 7):

Not really an answer, but since the Pathable site isn't all that conducive for a public meeting, here's where the meetup is planned:

> StackExchange reserved table at Tuesday's lunch.
>
> 1501 S Neil St
>
> Champaign, IL 61820
>
> Tuesday, October 20th @ 12:00 pm CDT

Comment: What day? .....

Comment: @alancalvitti Oops. Fixed. And I'll send you an invite.

Comment: Tue night is the WRI sponsored networking dinner, 6-9 - I'm attending. Any chance you can move this to Wed? - There's a closing gathering on Thur eve as well.

Comment: @kale are we set up for Wed? Please send me the invite too.

Comment: @alancalvitti There's a keynote dinner on Wednesday. Maybe we could do a meetup a little earlier on Tuesday at the expense of a session?

Comment: What about getting together for lunch 12-12:15pm any day?

Comment: @kale, sounds good. Waiting for invite.

Comment: @alancalvitti, Zviovich I've moved it to lunchtime on the 20th. Hopefully more people can attend then...

Comment: Sounds good. I'm in a session that finishes at noon on Tuesday so I may be a few mins late.

Comment: All, @brettchampion has reserved us a table in the ballroom for lunch on Tuesday. It'll have a StackExchange sign displayed.

Comment: Note comment, @Edmund. I'll update the meeting for the others.

Answer (score 7):

Very proud to report that at least four of the 10 innovator awards went to Mma.SE members - congrats to kale, Paul Abbott and Philip Maymin (and me). If there are others amongst the winners please edit this answer.

I'd post pictures but this doesn't seem possible from a phone.

---

(from the Wolfram Twitter account)

[image: Innovator Award winners]

Comment: Congrats everybody!

Comment: Which one is Stephen Wolfram?

Comment: Probably the guy who looks like a tanned George Clooney.

Answer (score 4):

Just noticed this. I am here. Hi!

Comment: Good to get to meet you Caitlin

Answer (score 2):

Related, free post-conference workshop in Chicago on WL for data, cloud, STEM >  [Post WTC2015 workshop on WL, data, cloud, STEM // Chicago](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/post-wtc2015-workshop-on-wl-data-cloud-stem-chicago)