# Post WTC2015 workshop on WL, data, cloud, STEM // Chicago

Tags: discussion

After WTC, if there's sufficient interest, I'd like to host a 1/2-day or 1-day independent workshop:

**>> WL for data, cloud enablers and emerging business models <<**

at this nice Lincon Park, Chicago, Airbnb one of Fri 23--Mon 26 // *free pizza, beer & wine* // topics >>

- Expanded version of my ["functional Dataset toolkit"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9i-pfGwn22sQ1IzU0JMTEplVXM/view?usp=sharing) pres [Wed 21 2:30] //   walkthrough our Google Drive based scientific workflow // ongoing projects on  health IT design at VA San Diego & UCSD
- A short list of tech & sci innovations in 2015
- Cloud technologies as enablers // emerging business models in healthcare & biomed [eg Emerald Cloud Lab], advanced manufacturing, enterprise analytics, real-time economy
- Modernize STEM global workforce // computer based math // can social tools like SE scale where WRI's tech support can't? // agile dev vs technical debt
- Mathematica challenges >> composite key design to optimize time-series association data // build an interactive diff highlighter for clinical progress notes // operator form for everything - how to get there

Will share my notebook API, screenshare join.me.

[image]

Comment: this sounds interesting Alan. Any chance some notebooks or video could be posted later or streaming?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, added link to presention notebook - may change a bit by Wed.

Comment: Preference on days? Id rather do Fri fresh from the meeting, but w/ transit it would have to be later in the day.

Comment: thanks @alancalvitti . Hope the workshop goes well. All the best